# PSR-0 Autoload Error

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader, psr-0

I want use composer for my projects.

My project structure:

```
src
   Easycache
       Common
           Cache
               Cache.php
               CacheInterface.php
               ...
```

Namespace

```
namespace Easycache\Common\Cache
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Easycache": "src/"}
}
```

Where error ?
Thanks...

Comment: are you getting an error, if so, which one?

Comment: I've "psr-0": {"": "src/"} in my project, and did you execute "php composer.phar update" ?  You need to include the "vendor/autoload.php" file too.

Comment: You can se my project this repo {
    "require": {
     "kmlkarakas/easycache": "dev-master"
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have autoload error but remember that when you run composer install or composer update you need to use generated autoloader first that is in vendor/autoload if your application still does not see your files, check the generated autoload namespaces and directiories in vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

Also remember to follow psr-0 standard witch says in file Cache.php you need to have class named Cache and it will be reachable under

```
use Easycache\Common\Cache\Cache;
```

And for the future, when you ask question say what problem or error is becouse no one here can read in your mind. (Or paste in the exception/error from php)